# Creating a C struct with multiple variable length arrays as members

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a C struct such that several array members can have variable lengths, something like this:

```
#define MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH 10
typedef struct A {
    int a;
    int b[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int c[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
} A;
```

Unfortunately, the struct needs to be in continuous memory to function in a larger process, so creating pointers for `b` and `c` and malloc'ing after creating the struct isn't viable. It's not ideal to make `MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH` something huge, as every time a struct was created, a large amount of memory would be held up. Because of how C checks bounds (or lack thereof), it's a pretty easy process to make the last array element of a struct variable length, something like this:

```
int desired_length = 20;
size_t bytes = offsetof(A, c[desired_length]);
A *tmp_struct = malloc(bytes);
```

The process to make `b` changeable in length seems less straightforward. Off the top of my head, it could be possible to combine `b` and `c` into one array if they're both numerical (float and double, int and float, etc) and create members for end positions of each section of the array. Something like this:

```
#define MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH 10
typedef struct A {
    int a;
    int b_length;
    int c_length;
    int arr[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
} A;


int desired_b = 10;
int desired_c = 10;
size_t bytes = offsetof(A, arr[desired_b + desired_c]);
A *tmp_struct = malloc(bytes);
tmp_struct->b_length = desired_b;
tmp_struct->c_length = desried_c;

for (int i = 0; i < tmp_struct->b_length; i++) {
    int b_element = tmp_struct->arr[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < tmp_struct->c_length; j++) {
        int c_element = tmp_struct->arr[tmp_struct->b_length + j];
    }
}
```

This seems pretty unwieldy and doesn't extend to any nonnumerical datatypes. Is there a way to do this that can be extended to other datatypes?

Comment: Why not use dynamic allocation for `a` and `b`, and flatten into a single array when you need to pass it to the other code that needs it to be contiguous?

Comment: C doesn't have any built-in way to have multiple flexible array members. Only the last struct member can be a FAM.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not have any VLAs here so the subject is very confusing.

> Unfortunately, the struct needs to be in continuous memory to function
> in a larger process

2. Use structs to have more complicated data sets and use flexible array members and you will get exactly what you want.

```
typedef struct A {
    size_t size;
    int data[][2];
} A;


typedef struct B {
    size_t size;
    struct {
        int a,b,c,d;
        char *x;
        double f;
        int arr[5][10];
    }data[];
} B;

B *allocateB(size_t size)
{
    B *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) + size * sizeof(ptr -> data[0]));
    if(ptr) ptr -> size = size;
    return ptr;   
}

A *allocateA(size_t size)
{
    A *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) + size * sizeof(ptr -> data[0]));
    if(ptr) ptr -> size = size;
    return ptr;   
}
```

You can `realloc` them id you want to change the size.

Answer (score 0):

One can have an allocated chunk of storage represent a structure containing offsets to other structures within the chunk, followed by the contents of those other structures.  Accessing the storage would require converting the header pointer into a character pointer, adding the appropriate offset, and then converting to a pointer of the proper structure type.  The Effective Type rules would allow storage to be used in this way provided that no portion of a structure which has *ever* been written using any particular type is ever used to represent data as any contrary type (as interpreted by clang and gcc, if storage is written using more than one type in its lifetime, it may only be read using lvalues that are compatible with *all* such types).  If it may be necessary to resize a chunk of storage and move the later items in the allocation, code should be built with the `-fno-strict-aliasing flag` to ensure that compilers don't try to reorder accesses using different types across each other.